# UDK - Determing what version a UE3 project is

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

So I was passed another programmers UE3 project and I haven't touched anything Unreal since some modding back in the early 2000s.

The first question I was asked is what version of UE3 is it running so I pull up the project in VS2010/nFringe and start looking around in there... The script files all have any useful headers removed and looking at the projects assembly info provided no answers. The directory structure also provided no answers.

So is there an easy way to determine what version of UE3 is used in this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I found is by going into the build.properties file in the Binaries folder and looking at the engineVersion.

Example
10897 = Feb 2013 Beta 1
10900 = Feb 2013 Beta 2